# Python "local variable 'pc' referenced before assignment" issue in basic decomplier

Tags: python, string, variables, hex, emulation

A friend and myself are working on creating a basic proof-of-concept decompiler that takes a string of hex values and returns a more readable version. Our code is listed below

```
testProgram = "00 00 FF 55 47 00"
# should look like this
# NOP
# NOP
# MOV 55 47
# NOP

pc = 0
output = ""

def byte(int):
    return testProgram[3 * int:3 * int + 2]

def interpret():

    currentByte = byte(pc)

    if currentByte == "00":
        pc += 1
        return "NOP"

    if currentByte == "FF":
        returner = "MOV " + byte(pc + 1) + " " + byte(pc + 2)
        pc += 3
        return returner

while(byte(pc) != ""):
    output += interpret() + "\n"

print(output)
```

however, running the code tells us this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BasicTest.py", line 62, in <module>
    output += interpret() + "\n"
  File "BasicTest.py", line 50, in interpret
    currentByte = byte(pc)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pc' referenced before assignment
```

Because pc is a global variable, shouldn't it be usable from anywhere? Any and all help is appreciate - if you spot other errors, feel free to leave a comment pointing them out!

Answer (score 4):

Been seeing this a lot lately. When you do

```
if currentByte == "00":
    pc += 1  # <----------
    return "NOP"
```

You're assigning to the local variable `pc`, but `pc` isn't declared yet in the local scope. If you want to modify the global `pc` you need to declare that explicitly at the top of the function

```
global pc
```